# Firestore access denied

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

> W/Firestore(21122): (24.7.0) [WatchStream]: (6db20e0) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission denied on resource project resturant., cause=null}.

Whenever i run my flutter app it shows this message in the console, and it does not fetch any data from the database.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
class ard extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<ard> createState() => _ardState();
}

class _ardState extends State<ard> {
  final Cartcontroller = Get.put(cartcontrol());

  final _productstream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return
      Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true,leading:IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(BuildContext context)=>Loginform()))
            ,icon: Icon(Icons.person),tooltip:"Login" ,),

            title: Text('Al Baik'),backgroundColor: Colors.red,automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                Cartcontroller.Total();
              },child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            ),
            body:
            Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.white54,toolbarHeight: 30,
              leading: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: () {},icon:Icon(Icons.local_drink_rounded) ,
                      style:ElevatedButton.styleFrom(fixedSize: Size.fromWidth(55.0),backgroundColor: Colors.white10 ,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))
                      ),
                      label: Text(""),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
              body:
              StreamBuilder(
                stream: _productstream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text('connection error');
                  }
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Text("Loading");
                  }
                  var Docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: Docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
                      return Text(Docs[index]['name']);
                      }
                  );
                }
              )
               ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code.

Comment: Your question should show the code (a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)) that doesn't work the way you expect. Without that, it's highly unlikely that you'll get good feedback on what's wrong and how to fix it. We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves with the instructions you provide.

Comment: sorry it did not paste my code the first time

Answer (score 0):

You need a boolean `true` value after the `allow` rule to allow access, separated with `:`. Try this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no that did not work unfortunately the same error is happening.

Comment: Is your application properly registered in Firebase console under Project settings / General? You might need to add SHA keys etc.